# MIPS - Checking if an element of an array is the null-terminating character

Tags: string, mips

So I'm trying to write a function that will find the length of a string in MIPS.

I'm walking/traversing along the array, loading each character, and I want to compare each character to the null-terminating character to see if the string has "ended". At each successive iteration, I increment a counter, and then store the counter in $v0 once the string has "ended". However, how do I compare whether the current loaded character is the null terminating character, "\0"? More specifically, how do I represent this null-terminating character? Is it $zero, as I have done below? If so, then what else am I doing wrong? Getting an address error.

```
.data
msg1:.asciiz "Please insert text (max 20 characters): "
msg2:.asciiz "\nThe length of the text is: "

newline: .asciiz "\n"

str1: .space 20
.text
.globl main
main:
addi $v0, $v0,4
la $a0,msg1
syscall #print msg1
li $v0,8
la $a0,str1
addi $a1,$zero,20
syscall   #get string 1

la $a0,str1  #pass address of str1
jal len

len: 
addi $t2, $zero, 0 # $t2 is what we want to return in the end -- the count of the length of the character array
addi $s1, $zero, 0 # Index i for array traversing | init. to 0 | i = 0

Loop:

add $s1, $s1, $a0 # Adds the location of the index to the location of the base of the array | $t1 is now the location of: array[index]
lw $t0, 0($s1)

beq $t0, $zero, exit
addi $t2, $t2, 1 # Count = Count + 1
addi $s1, $s1, 1 # i = i + 1
j Loop

exit: 
la $a0,msg2 
li $v0,4
syscall
move $a0,$t0 #output the results 
li $v0,1
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: I've added the homework tag, feel free to remove it if this isn't homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are processing a string of bytes, and that you are looking for the zero byte at the end of the string, you should be using `lbu $t0, 0($s1)`.  `lbu` means "load byte without sign extension". Then you can compare `$t0` with the `$zero` register.  Your current code uses `lw $t0, 0($s1)` which loads 4 bytes into `$t0`.

There are some other bugs in your code, but I'll leave them to you to figure out, since this looks like homework.

Answer (score 1):

the following program computes the length of the string

```
.data   
theStr: .asciiz "berjee"
.text
main:
    li $s1, 0
    la $s0, theStr

loop:
    lb $a0, 0($s0)
    beqz $a0, out
    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    j loop

out:
    li $v0, 1
    add $a0, $0, $s1
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Just to offer a bit more explanation for this answer, `lb $a0, 0($s0)` loads the current byte offset of the string referenced by address in the register `$s0` into the register `$a0` and `beqz $a0, out` is the null termination check, comparing the byte in `$a0` with 0 and terminating the loop if they're equal.